# Rest Assured - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: java, rest-assured, sslexception

I am trying to hit a restful service hosted in AWS through the corporate proxy using RestAssured, but getting javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? Can some one please help identify what needs to be done to resolve this issue

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class Rough {

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.proxy("proxy.abc.com", 8080,"https");
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation("SSL");
    }

    @Test
    public void testService() {
                        String apiURL = "https://api-aws-cs-dev.abc.com/cs/customer/v1/accountservices/public/preload";
                        String apiBody = "{}";
                        RequestSpecBuilder requestSpecBuilder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
                        requestSpecBuilder.setBody(apiBody);
                        requestSpecBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        requestSpecBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        requestSpecBuilder.addQueryParam("version", "1");                  
                        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = requestSpecBuilder.build();
                        Response r  = given().log().everything().spec(requestSpecification).post(apiURL);
                        System.out.println(r.getBody().prettyPrint());          
    }
}
```

Exception :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
```

~Thanks